# How can you make an escaping completion handler argument optional?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a method as follows, sometimes being called with a completion handler and other times not, how can I make it optional?

```
func someFunc(completion: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Looked at several last questions but can't apply any of their answers

Comment: why don't you make completion params optionals or the completion does not have a params, and even is not necessary alway to call the completion if you don't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a default value

```
func someFunc(completion: @escaping () -> Void = {}) {
    completion()
}
```

and call it with or without a closure

```
someFunc()
someFunc(completion: {...})
```